# Rich text editor that does NOT use HTML

Tags: php, javascript, textfield

I'm looking to add a light text editor (in php/js), much like the one found here in stackoverflow, wikipedia, forums, etc. to my application to get input from the user.

I do not want to use ones solutions like TinyMCE because they simply send back and forth HTML. The HTML then needs to be sanitized and that's already so much resource wasted.

Does anyone know any that can be commercially used? Free or paid.

Thank you.

Comment: [so] uses Markdown (which IMHO is far superior to wikipedia's and forum's syntax). You can search for that.

Comment: You may try Code Mirror? http://codemirror.net/

Comment: wtf, why are ppl closing this?

Comment: I can understand why marking this as "not constructive" (I won't) but I don't understand the "off topic"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackoverflow uses markdown. I believe I use this version on my site https://github.com/derobins/wmd and this for the C# backend http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/ I do remember needing to tweak the javascript settings and css/html but its not very hard

Comment: Also found this list very useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Markdown_implementations